# Winsock Join MAC ADDRESS Multicast group

Tags: winsock, multicast, ethernet, raw-ethernet

Is there a way to join an Ethernet multicast group?  All documentation I found is about adding an IP group.

I just want to receive the Cisco CDP packet that is sent to the MAC address 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OID part of the MAC address you give (01:00:0C) isn't the same as the one used for IPv4 multicast (01:00:5E), so you can't use anything in Winsock to send this packet.  Even raw sockets won't work, because that doesn't let you dig down to the Ethernet layer.

What you need is [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/) or something like it, with which you can construct raw Ethernet frames and receive answering packets at that same level.